How to use outlook add-in with internal domain?
We are developing outlook add-in based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-aspnet.
It works fine on localhost, but we need to test it on internal domains as well.
The Azure registration for this add-in requires the "Application ID URI" to contain either localhost or a verified domain (api://<fully-qualified-domain-name>/<app-id>).
Is there any way to run the add-in with an internal domain without verifying a custom domain?
It is strange that Redirect URI does not have verified domain validation, but Application ID URI has...
Thank you in advance.

Already implemented using OfficeDialog API
